# Ruby PKCS7: added "\r" bytes are breaking decryption

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, pkcs#7

Using Ruby's OpenSSL lib, when I try to both encrypt and sign a message as a PKCS7, I find that some extra `\r` characters get inserted, and I can't decrypt the message.

Below I have a toy example. I more thorough example is available on [this paste](https://pastebin.com/4WZjKcRB).

```rb
# The sender encrypts the message
crypted = OpenSSL::PKCS7.encrypt([recipient_cert], "message").to_der
# The sender signs the message
signed = OpenSSL::PKCS7.sign(sender_cert, sender_key, crypted).to_der

# The recipient extracts data from the signed PKCS7
p7_signed = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(signed)
store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
p7_signed.verify(nil, store, nil, OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOVERIFY)
unsigned = p7_signed.data

# The tries to decrypt the data
OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(unsigned).decrypt(recipient_key, recipient_cert)
# => ArgumentError: Could not parse the PKCS7: nested asn1 error
```

Why does the data extracted from `p7_signed` not match the data in `crypted`? When I examine the two, I find that `unsigned` contains a few `\r` characters here and there which `crypted` does not have. What can I do about this?

(I'm doing this on Linux, in case the question of CRLF vs LF comes up.)

Comment: well, it does look like at least one \n was replaced with \r\n.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk indeed. I noticed instances of `\n` being replaced with `\r\n`, but I don't know what to do about it. I couldn't retroactively replace all instances of `\r\n` with `\n` because the real-world example message I was working with also presented an instance of `\r\n` in `crypted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should supply the `PKCS7_BINARY` flag to `PKCS7.sign()`, probably available as `OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY`. I don't know Ruby at all but reading the [docs at ruby-doc.org](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS7.html) and the [openssl man pages](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/PKCS7_sign.html) leads me to believe this is the issue.

From the openssl man page for PKCS7 (with a minor correction by me):

> Normally the supplied content is translated into MIME canonical format
> (as required by the S/MIME specifications), but if PKCS7_BINARY is set no
> translation occurs. This option should be used if the supplied data is
> in binary format otherwise the translation will corrupt it.

Since your input to the `OpenSSL::PKCS7.sign(...)` is the DER-encoded output from `OpenSSL::PKCS7.encrypt(...)`, that's essentially a binary format and not text.